# Link different charts together using Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, charts, jqplot, pie-chart

I'm searching for a JavaScript library through which i can create charts that link to other charts or embed them. For example, let's say we have a pie chart, if someone clicks on a pie's slice, another different chart appears.

I'm using the Google Charts API and jqPlot at the moment, but so far I haven't found a way to add links or js functions when someone is clicking on a chart's element. Any help for any library will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They all allow event handling

Here is one

http://g.raphaeljs.com/piechart2.html